# How to force Apollo Query component to re-run query when parent component re-renders

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo Client's `<Query>` within a component that is re-rendered when state is changed within a lifecycle method. I wish to have my `<Query>` component re-run the query because I know that data has changed.
It appears that Query component is using a cache that needs to be invalidated before query is re-run.

I'm using a wonky workaround that caches the `refetch` callback from the render prop in the parent component, but it feels wrong. I'll post my approach in the answers if anyone is interested.

My code looks something like this. I removed `loading` and `error` handling from query as well as some other detail for brevity.

```js
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.refetchId !== prevProps.refetchId) {
      const otherData = this.processData() // do something
      this.setState({otherData}) // this forces component to reload
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { otherData } = this.state

    return (
      <Query query={MY_QUERY}>
        {({ data }) => {
          return <ChildComponent gqlData={data} stateData={otherData} />
        }}
      </Query>
    )
  }
}
```

**How do I force `<Query>` to fetch new data to pass to `<ChildComponent>`?**

Even though `ParentComponent` re-renders when props or state change, `Query` doesn't re-run. `ChildComponent` gets an updated `stateData` prop, but has a stale `gqlData` prop. As I understand Apollo's query cache need to be invalidated, but I'm not sure.

Please note that passing `refetch` to ChildComponent is not the answer because it only displays information from GraphQL and wouldn't know when to refetch. I don't want to introduce timers or otherwise complicate `ChildComponent` to solve this - it doesn't need to know about this complexity or data fetching concerns.

Comment: I added couple options, I always used the first one, the second method would not work if you do not want to pass anything down.

Answer (score 21):

I had almost a similar situation which I solved with `fetchPolicy` attribute:

`<Query fetchPolicy="no-cache"` ...

The task was to load some details from server by clicking on a list item.

And if I wanted to add an action to force re-fetching the query (such as modifying the details), I first assigned the `refetch` to `this.refetch`:

```
<Query fetchPolicy="no-cache" query={GET_ACCOUNT_DETAILS} variables=... }}>
  {({ data: { account }, loading, refetch }) => {
  this.refetch = refetch;
...
```

And in the specific action that I wanted the refetch to happen, I called:

```
this.refetch();
```

Comment: This was the simplest solution for me

Comment: This worked like a charm.  Easiest solution I've found so far.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the already accepted answer above there are 2 ways of achieving this.

If all you need is getting data from the graphql server to generate a list every time a component is mounted you have these options:

1. Use the option `fetchPolicy="no-cache"`

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { result, loading, error } = useMyQuery(
      () => {
        return { date: new Date() }
      },
      {
        pollInterval: 15 * 60 * 1000, // refresh data every 15 min
        fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
      }
    )
```

2. Use the `refetch()` method while keeping the cache in place:

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { result, loading, error}, refetch } = useMyQuery(
      () => {
        return { date: new Date() }
      },
      {
        pollInterval: 15 * 60 * 1000, // refresh data every 15 min
      }
    )

    if (!loading.value) void refetch()
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you refetch in parent component? Once the parent component get an update, then you can evaluate whether to trigger a fetch or not.

I have done it without using `Query` like the following:

```
class ParentComp extends React.Component {

    lifeCycleHook(e) { //here
        // call your query here
        this.props.someQuery()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child Comp data={this.props.data.key}> //child would only need to render data
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default graphql(someQuery)(SongCreate);
```

So you can trigger your fetch anytime you want it to. You can get the query as a `prop` in this case.

For your case, you would put your query into a prop using `export default graphql(addSongQuery)(SongCreate);`. Then call it in your lifecyclehooks `DidUpdate`.

Another options is to use `refetch` on Query.

```
<Query
    query={GET_DOG_PHOTO}
    variables={{ breed }}
    skip={!breed}
  >
    {({ loading, error, data, refetch }) => {
      if (loading) return null;
      if (error) return `Error!: ${error}`;

      return (
        <div>
          <img
            src={data.dog.displayImage}
            style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }}
          />
          <button onClick={() => refetch()}>Refetch!</button>
        </div>
      );
    }}
  </Query>
```

The second method would require you pass something down to your child, which isn't really all that bad.

Comment: in both of your examples child component does something to trigger a rerender. as described in the question, child component doesn't know _when_ to trigger a rerender (it's not interactive). thanks, but this is not really what i'm after

Comment: no, the first one does not. The parent has the query as a prop, and you can `re-render` using lifecycle hooks.

Comment: ah, I see. now that you've simplified it, it's easier to follow. thanks.

Comment: Great! Glad to be working @AndreiR. Let me know how it turns out. If works, could you up-vote and accept the answer for other viewers? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the Query component doesn't necessarily need to be inside this `ParentComponent`.

In that case, I would move the Query component up, since I would still be able to render other stuff while I don't have results in the `ChildComponent`. And then I would have access to the [`query.refetch`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#refetching) method.

Note that in the example I added the `graphql` hoc, but you can still use Query component around `<ParentComponent />`.

```js
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.refetchId !== prevProps.refetchId) {
            const otherData = this.processData() // do something

            //   won't need this anymore, since refetch will cause the Parent component to rerender)
            //   this.setState({otherData}) // this forces component to reload 

            this.props.myQuery.refetch(); // >>> Refetch here!
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {
            otherData
        } = this.state;

        return <ChildComponent gqlData={this.props.myQuery} stateData={otherData} />;
    }
}

export graphql(MY_QUERY, {
    name: 'myQuery'
})(ParentComponent);
```

Comment: Thanks. This opened my eyes a bit. Basically, `<Query>` is a poor choice for almost any use case other than the most trivial ones.

Comment: Yes. I end up not using it that much. 
This this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

As promised, here's my hacky workaround

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.refetchId !== prevProps.refetchId) {
      const otherData = this.processData() // do something
      this.setState({otherData})
      if (this.refetch) {
        this.refetch()
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { otherData } = this.state
    const setRefetch = refetch => {this.refetch = refetch}
    return (
      <Query query={MY_QUERY}>
        {({ data, refetch }) => {
          setRefetch(refetch)
          return <ChildComponent gqlData={data} stateData={otherData} />
        }}
      </Query>
    )
  }
}
```